How to use kzalloc and GFP_DMA to allocate buffers for mmap in Linux kernel modules?
We all know that the function used to dynamically apply memory in user space is malloc(), which is used consistently on various operating systems, and the corresponding user space memory release function is free(). Attention: The dynamically requested memory must be released after use, otherwise it will cause memory leaks. If the memory leak occurs in kernel space, it will cause system crashes.
So, how to apply for memory in kernel space? We usually use functions such as kmalloc(), kzalloc(), vmalloc(), etc. Below, we will introduce the usage of these functions and their differences.
kmalloc()
Function prototype:
void *kmalloc(size_t size, gfp_t flags)；
The memory requested by kmalloc() is located in the physical memory mapping area and is physically continuous. They have only a fixed offset from the real physical address. Due to the existence of a simple conversion relationship, there is a limit on the size of the requested memory, which cannot exceed 128KB.
Commonly used flags (methods for allocating memory):
GFP_ATOMIC - The process of allocating memory is an atomic process that is not interrupted by high priority processes or interrupts;
GFP_KERNEL - Normal memory allocation;
In general, memory only needs to be physically contiguous when it needs to be DMA accessed, but for performance reasons, the kernel generally uses kmalloc(), and vmalloc() is only used when a large block of memory needs to be obtained. For example, when a module is dynamically loaded into the kernel, it is loaded onto the memory allocated by vmalloc().
The common characteristics of kmalloc(), kzalloc(), and vmalloc() are:
